# http to https pages not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have entered code in my htaccess file to redirect from non-www to www and from http to https. It works for the home page but not for some of the other pages on the site. So for example it works on www.example.com but not www.example.com/contactus. The code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Make sure you've cleared your browser cache. The code you posted should work OK. There's nothing in those redirects that differentiates the home page from any other page. (Incidentally, any custom directives should be placed outside/above the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, otherwise WP may override them in a future update.

Comment: Thanks now got it working.